# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 : getSublistValue() Not Returning Value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Unfortunately, it appears that when you create an Invoice from a custom transaction, NetSuite doesn't populate the native 'createdfrom' field. My attempt to work-around the issue by creating a custom reference field (i.e. `custbody_invoicecreatedfrom`) results in the `getSublistValue()` function returning an empty result, even through the internal ID is displayed correctly on the apply sublist line of the payment (XML).  I tried using `getSublistText()` as well, but that didn't work either. I have no problem getting the native sublist values (i.e. record browser), but the custom field will not return a value. Any suggestions?

```
//Loop through all of the Invoices Applied to the Payment
for (var k = 0; k < invoiceCount; k++) {
    var invoiceCreatedFrom = paymentSubmitted.getSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'apply',
    fieldId: 'custbody_invoicecreatedfrom',
    line: k
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`custbody_invoicecreatedfrom` is not a Sublist field, as indicated by the `custbody` prefix; `getSublistValue` will only return values from Sublist columns.

Answer (score 0):

custbody_invoicecreatedfrom is not a Sublist field, as indicated by the custody prefix then it should be Header field or main field;
To get the text from the above filed you need to write code like.

record.getText({
fieldId:'custbody_invoicecreatedfrom'
});